# How can I export every frame vertex animation data?

Tags: python

I want to export every frame vertex positions something like this:

```
Frame 1
<Vector (1.0016, 1.0085, 1.0011)>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0196, -1.0437, 0.9638)>
Frame 2
<Vector (1.0061, 1.0334, 1.0044)>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0148, -1.0692, 0.9606)>
Frame 3
<Vector (1.0134, 1.0734, 1.0097)>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (1.0071, -1.1103, 0.9555)>
Frame 4
<Vector (1.0355, 1.1941, 1.0257)>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, -1.0000)>
<Vector (0.9837, -1.2344, 0.9400)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use for-loop to export every frame positions:

```
import bpy

sce = bpy.context.scene
f = open("props.txt", "w")
for frame in range(sce.frame_start, sce.frame_end+1):
    sce.frame_set(frame)

    
    me = bpy.context.object.data   
    print("Frame %i" % frame, file=f)     
    for v in me.vertices:
     print(v.co.xyz, file=f)
 
f.close()
```